# How to make a RESTful query to the elasticsearch search API for logs within a certain @timestamp range.

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to query elasticsearch for all logs that have a @timestamp within a certain range. This is being done by a $.get() request using jQuery. My attempts so far have resulted in queries not within the time range. I am listing the logs on my own HTML page and although I have tried different query messages I always get one of two responses, one with times starting at 4:25 and the other with times starting at 6:39. I don't know if this is useless information but I thought it could be useful in understanding the nature of the problem. 
So this is the message I have written myself.

```
{
        "query" : {
        "filtered": {
            "query" : { "match_all" : {}},
            "filter": {
                "range" : {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "from" : 1393580102248,
                        "to" : 1393583702248
                    }
                }
            }

        }       
    }
}
```

We are also using Kibana (working) and I have tried copying and pasting the same exact query Kibana uses, with the SAME results as my query above.

```
{
  "query": {
"filtered": {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "from": 1393580102248,
              "to": 1393583702248
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_all": {}
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
 },
  "highlight": {
"fields": {},
"fragment_size": 2147483647,
"pre_tags": [
  "@start-highlight@"
],
"post_tags": [
  "@end-highlight@"
]
  },
  "size": 500,
  "sort": [
{
  "@timestamp": {
    "order": "desc"
  }
}
 ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I can change the time range as well and I still get the same results.

Comment: are you sure that you have docs in that range you are not seeing with the query? are you sure you docs were all indexed with @timestamp as a field? Can you show a sample doc? Those timestamps are Fri Feb 28 2014 04:35:02 GMT-0500 (EST) - Fri Feb 28 2014 05:35:02 GMT-0500 (EST) is that right?

Comment: the queries work with a curl -XGET request, just not with the jQuery $.get request. The answer to why that is is the answer to this question..